# Unable to compress excel file (XLSX or XLS) using java

Tags: java

In one of java sprint MVC based application, i need to compress size of excel file, because application is unable to send email attachment.
any one please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The formats with 'x' at the end are actually zip archives, so any more compression is moot. You could unzip the Excel sheet and look for data based compression.

- Images in lower resolution.
- Excel XML with less repetition of styles, attributes.
- Repeated expressions.
- Maybe there are embedded fonts.

Comment: thanks joop Eggen, actually this excel file is autogenerated through java application for reporting purpose so user have no option to change any thing manually

Comment: But you could at least unzip and check whether there are artifacts in the .xlsx like a MB corporate logo or such. Postprocessing the .xslx is indeed overcomplicated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tutorial of how to Zip single/multiple files in Java which should get you what you require:
http://www.kscodes.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-java/

Comment: Hello Raza, this tutorial is provide codebase for zip one or more file, but my problem is not same. i need to reduce size of any excel file